# How can I login to YouTube and get the content of this page?

Tags: php, youtube-api

Please help me get the content of page like:

```
http://www.youtube.com/my_videos_annotate?feature=vm&v=someVideoId
```

using PHP/Curl.

I think I need first log into YouTube's service, but don't know how to do this.

Comment: do you want to get the content of the page or only the video?

Comment: [This could possibly help you.](https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_php) If not, let me know.

Comment: content of page with loged user (I have email/password)

Comment: I tried <http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4895802/php-curl-problems> and some equals CURL+cookies solutions, I receive that 'I need turn on cookies'

Answer (score 0):

Use youtube-api 
**Example**

```
$feedURL = 'http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/**ACCOUNTNAME**/uploads?max-results=50';
$sxml = simplexml_load_file($feedURL);
$i=0;
foreach ($sxml->entry as $entry) {
      $media = $entry->children('media', true);
      $watch = (string)$media->group->player->attributes()->url;
      $thumbnail = (string)$media->group->thumbnail[0]->attributes()->url;
        $input = array('http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=','&feature=youtube_gdata_player');
        $change = array('','') ;
        $link = @str_replace ($input ,$change, $watch);


      echo $link.'</br>';
      echo $thumbnail.'</br>'; //**thumbnail
      echo $media->group->title.'</br>'; //**title
      echo $media->group->description.'</br>'; //**description
}
```

Hope This will help

Comment: sorry, but this works for xml-data, http://www.youtube.com/my_videos_annotate?feature=vm&v=someVideoId is html-page. And this page only can be opened for user if he/she author of someVideoId. And there no API for get content of editing annotations pages.